# Use object from one class as attribute for another class

Tags: python

I am trying to make a circle which asks *only* for a center and radius. Here is my code:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print_point(self):
        print(f"Point: {self.x, self.y}")


class Circle:

    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def print_circle(self):
        print(f"Circle: {(self.center), self.radius}")


p1 = Point(150, 100)
c1 = Circle(p1, 75)
c1.print_circle()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: What it is the printed error? And in a class, if you want to give a str representation, you must override the method `__str__()`, so change `print_circle()` and `print_point()`.

Comment: Or `__repr__`, if you make it look more [_"like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value"_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

Comment: Seems as if `def __repr__(self): return f'Point: ({self.x}, {self.y})'` in the `Point` class is all we need.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the `__repr__` method to your point class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Point: {self.x, self.y}"


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def print_circle(self):
        print(f"Circle: {((self.center)), self.radius}")

p1 = Point(150, 100)
c1 = Circle(p1, 75)
c1.print_circle()
```

Comment: and probably `print_circle --> __repr__` on the `Circle` class too

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually getting any info from the class that's being passed, and just trying to print the object itself. I haven't tested this code myself but try

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print_point(self):
        print(f"Point: {self.x, self.y}")


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def print_circle(self):
        print(f"Circle: {((self.center.x),(self.center.y)), self.radius}")

p1 = Point(150, 100)
c1 = Circle(p1, 75)
c1.print_circle()
```

or use another function that returns the string to be printed:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print_point(self):
        print(f"Point: {self.x, self.y}")
    
    def get_point(self):
        return f'Point: {self.x, self.y}'


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def print_circle(self):
        print(f"Circle: {self.center.get_point()},{self.radius}")

p1 = Point(150, 100)
c1 = Circle(p1, 75)
c1.print_circle()
```